# Disable IIS service on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have a conflict between Apache and IIS on Windows Server 2008.  They both want control over port 80; we don't use IIS for anything so I wanted to disable the service.

However I can't find it anywhere!  Is this something that can be disabled?  I'd rather disable than remove the feature, in case anything IS using IIS after all.

Thanks in advance 
Duncan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't just disable the service.  Go to your server manager and remove the Web Server role from the machine. That will make sure something doesn't accidentally (or maliciously) start the service again for some reason.  It will keep windows update from wanting to install patches for IIS (unless you install it again) and is just cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1**

<del>If you want to be able to start the service ad-hoc later, the you could just disable the Windows Service</del>

<del>IIS Admin Service</del>

*Update: this service is only there if you've enabled IIS 6 compatibility.*

This is the service to disable:

```
World Wide Web Publishing Service
```

**Option 2**

Remove the Web Server (IIS) Role. This will permanently remove the feature from your server. You'll have to add the role later if you think you'll need the service.

Comment: I'm looking for this in the Services panel but can't find it by that name - or is it by another name?  Thanks.

Comment: On English server, yes. I've checked it. Are you sure IIS is installed. Open "Server Manager" and open "Roles". Is there an item "Web Server (IIS)"?

Comment: Yes, Web Server (IIS) is in the Roles Summary, but I honestly can't see IIS Admin Service in the Services list!

Comment: Is it an US/English server? Did you sort the service list by name?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: the IIS admin service is not needed if you're not using IIS 6 compatibilty

Comment: Do you see the "World Wide Web Publishing Service"?

Comment: Thanks, yes I see the W3 Publishing Service, will remove the feature if this is recommended.

Comment: In Russian localization "Служба веб-публикаций"

Answer (score 3):

Change the port of IIS to another one. By default it's port is 80 but you can change it. So later you can use both.